# Search file and grep numeric range

Tags: grep, wildcards

I have a file which contains a column called salary.

This column has various salaries. Using grep I want to get all values between 10000 and 15000.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please provide the example input and expected output?

Comment: "columns" and "numeric range" scream `awk` (or `perl`) rather than `grep`

Comment: Hi Simon, this question is almost impossible to answer without some clarification. Especially the expected input file format, the number formatting and the output you are trying to get out of this

Comment: Specifically: what is the column separator; are any columns quoted (as in CSV exported from Excel); what reporting requirements have you (columns, totals etc). grep is usually very unsuitable for columned data.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: As grep search for the "format" of the string, not the value, you should analyze which format must have the numbers in the range you want:

```
10000
10001
  :
14857
  :
15000
```

If you look what are the possible digits, you could then devise a regular expression that check if the number has a format like this, i.e.

```
1. Has 5 digits.
2. Starts with 1.
3. The second digit can be 0,1,2,3,4,5.
4. The remaining digits don't matter (but each one have to be one digit from 0-9).
```

I recommend the site http://regex101.com for learning and testing regexes.